# Bigcommerce API where to fine client ID

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a store on bigcommerce and i need to access the customers registered on our store using there api.

I havent created any app over there. I need to access the customers registering on our store.
According to api i need to use client id which we get by creating an app.

```
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#request-headers
```

But actually i dont need to create a app i just want to use the store and fetch the customer details using the api into another application, can anyone please tell me how to get client id from the dashboard login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the legacy API (non-oAuth) credentials instead. 
Guide: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Legacy-API-Accounts